# WebKit encountered an internal error: WebKitErrorDomain:300

Tags: safari, webkit, internal

I'm experiencing a "Safari can't open the page. The error is: "WebKit encountered an internal error" (WebKitErrorDomain:300) on my site using safari browser. this appears when visited. but on other browsers it seems okay.

Does anyone know why and the solution for this. This would be a big help for everyone who has the same problem as mine. Thanks!

Comment: It might help if you share the site that causes this error